# Cannot access class variable in class method

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

```
class Bin():
a=[]
def g(self,e):
    self.a.append(e)
o=Bin()
o.g(3)
o.g(4)
o.g(5)
o.g(6)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 28, in <module>
File "<string>", line 9, in bs
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

> how to deal with this error? i wanna append the list inside the class with given elements and use the list 'a' in other class methods too.

Comment: Your indentation is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Fix your indentation:

```
class Bin:
    a = []

    def g(self, e):
        self.a.append(e)


o = Bin()
o.g(3)
o.g(4)
o.g(5)
o.g(6)

print(Bin.a)
```

Output : `[3, 4, 5, 6]`